# Cannont mount twice the same Vue 3 component

Tags: vuejs3, mount

Im' mounting a Vue 3 component as a loading animation during a frame loading with :

```
createApp(App).mount(e);
```

When the frame is loaded, the component is erased in the html by the frame content (but not by Vue I guess). This behaviour is managed by an external system of Vue.

When I'm trying to reload the component with the same command, the component is not displayed.

If I only mount again the component, I have the following warning in the console and the component is not displayed :

```
"[Vue warn]: App has already been mounted.
If you want to remount the same app, move your app creation logic into a factory function and create fresh app instances for each mount - e.g. `const createMyApp = () => createApp(App)`".
```

I've found also a way to replicate the issue with :

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount(el);
el.innerHtml = '';
app.mount(el);
```

I also try to unmount the component with no more success :

```
const app = createApp(App);
app.mount(el);
app.unmount();
app.mount(el);
```

So what is the correct way to display again the same vue component when it is erased externally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An far more better option is to use [Vue custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

First, create a classical SFC with ce.vue extension :

```
//test.ce.vue
<template>
    <div class="text-primary">Test</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'test',
};
</script>

<style>
    .text-primary {
        color: red;
    }

</style>
```

And then in the main script :

```
//app.js
import Test from 'test.ce.vue';
const testElement = defineCustomElement(Test);
customElements.define('test-element', testElement);

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('test-element'));
```

The component will be rendered as soon as  is detected in the document:

```
<test-component>
    #shadow-root (open)
        <style>
            .text-primary {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="text-primary">Test</div>
</test-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

To mount/unmount 2 instances of Vue, it is necessary to use render method.

So, for exemple below, this solution works :

```
var app = createApp({ render: () => h(App) })
app.mount(el);
el.innerHtml = '';
app = createApp({ render: () => h(App) })
app.mount(el);
```

Don't forget to import h() function with :

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
```